# How do I select the entire worksheet with vba code

Tags: vba, excel, select, range

I am new to vba code and I am trying to figure out how to select an entire excel file when dropping data into my template. I open a daily file everyday and the name changes and the number of rows and columns vary. How do I change the code to select the entire worksheet when automatically importing. The code I am using only selects the first row in the worksheet and not the entire worksheet.

Here's the code I have:

```
Sub ImportFile()       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

    Dim parentWorkbook As Excel.Workbook        
    Dim otherWorkbook As Excel.Workbook        
    Dim workbookName As Variant

    Set parentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    workbookName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*")

    If Not workbookName = False Then     
        Set otherWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(workbookName)        
        parentWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:AR2").Value = otherWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:AR2").Value     
        otherWorkbook.Close False 
        Set otherWorkbook = Nothing 
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just copy over  otherWorkbook.Sheets(1) into the first workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you say

```
parentWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1").Resize(otherWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count, otherWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count).Value = otherWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

try activating the worksheet before doing an actual select. so something like:

```
Sub SelectSingleSheet()
       Sheets("Sheet1").activate
       Sheets("Sheet1").Select //where 'Sheet1' is name of sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: No need to Activate. It is a bad practice to select object to do something with it.